# How to change compile SDKversion of a project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dependencies

I was working on a project in late 2018 and left that as it is after that now i want to make changes in it and publish it to the playstore. The project had the v7 dependencies 
&

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.andropc.wallpro"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
```

The app crashes after Android7.1 so how to run the app on above android versions what changes to make in the project or in dependencies to make it run in all versions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all android support libraries had mean migrated to androidx!(https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat)

But you can still use old dependencies as well (I would recommend you to switch to androidx).

You need to change `targetSdkVersion: 29` in `build.gradle` in order to support latest android version which is `android 10`.

Comment: i have to change the Target as well as CompileSDK right?

Comment: Compilesdkversion should be the your testing device's or emulator's android verison.You have to change targetSdkVersion, compileSdkVerison is optional

Comment: App crashed i did changed the compileSdk with 29 and buildToolsVersion to 29.0.0 and then run the app and it crashed. ok i am leaving both to 27 and 27.0.3 and just changing the TargetSdk.

Comment: 2020-05-15 00:00:22.895 1656-1715/? E/AudioPolicyIntefaceImpl: getInputForAttr permission denied: recording not allowed for uid 10025 pid 3451
2020-05-15 00:00:22.895 1656-1715/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecord() checkRecordThread_l failed

Comment: Have you this permission  android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO granted?